# Ensure my servlet filter runs before other dynamically added filters

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, filter, web.xml

I am trying to customize a third-party web application by adding servlet filters to web.xml.

It looks like my filters are not the first in the chain, even though I put their `filter-mapping` declarations at the very top of web.xml.

It seems like there are Spring Boot filters being inserted into the filter chain dynamically, via `ServletContext.addFilter` and `FilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns` with `isMatchAfter` set to false.  This means the dynamically-added filter mappings will be matched before any filter mappings declared in web.xml

I could do the same for my own filters as well, but how could I ensure that *my* filters will be run before the other filters that were added dynamically?  Is there any way to control the order explicitly with dynamically-added filters?

Comment: have you tried putting the filter-mapping at the very bottom instead?